# Unit Test Properties Duration Format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

When running unit tests from Visual Studio 2010, I see we are able to right click a specific test and select "View Test Results Details" from the Test Results window. My question is what format is used to display the duration property of a test? Is it hh:min:secs:ms ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks more like `hour:minute:fractional-seconds` to me.

Comment: Thank you! I want to display the format in hh:mins:seconds:milliseconds so I guess ill take the fraction of a seconds and multiply it by a thousand.

Answer (score 2):

It is `hours:minutes:seconds.fractions of a second`. Hopefully your individual tests never need those extra degrees of magnitude.